# Should I provide a Load() method for a cached data reader?

Tags: c#

I am creating a cached-based data reader that will parse a text-based file and load the contents into internal data structures. The data can then be accessed by various methods after the data is loaded. Should the reader class automatically load the data from disk in the constructor?

```
using(CachedDataReader reader = new CachedDataReader(@"C:\someFile.txt"))  // Load data now
{    
    string getValue = reader.GetValue(264);
}
```

or should I explicitly have an Open/Read/Load method to load the data?

```
using(CachedDataReader reader = new CachedDataReader(@"C:\someFile.txt")) 
{
    reader.Load() // Load data now
    string getValue = reader.GetValue(264);
}
```

Alternatively, I could add an optional boolean parameter to the constructor to autoLoad the data

```
public CachedDataReader(string filePath, bool autoLoad = true) 
{
     if(autoLoad) 
         Load();     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should the reader class automatically load the data from disk in the constructor?

Not according to [Microsoft's design practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229060%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Do minimal work in the constructor. Constructors should not do much work other than to capture the constructor parameters. The cost of any other processing should be delayed until required.

One practical reason why this could be a bad idea is if you have properties that must be set *before* loading the data.  If you do all of the work in the constructor then the only way to accomplish that is with constructor overload for every possible combination of properties.

Comment: For this case, there isn't really any properties that need to be set before reading.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be "neither, or both", in a sense.

As D Stanley wrote, constructor shouldn't do any real work, let alone disk I/O.

Separate `Load` method may be useful and people seem to like two phase initialization, but it also means you can access the object in an incorrect semi-initialized state when you forget to load the data.

Consider lazily loading the data the first time you want to access them, in your case in the `GetValue` method. BCL contains **[`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** that you can use.

The result might look like this:

```
class CachedDataReader
{
     private readonly Lazy<YourLoadedData> data;

     public CachedDataReader(string filePath)
     {
         // Prepare loading logic, but don't do anything yet.
         data = new Lazy<YourLoadedData>(() => Load(filePath));
     }

     private YourLoadedData Load(string filePath) { } // Load your data here.

     public string GetValue(int param)
     {
         // Access data.Value here to read cached data.
         // The Load method will be called the first time only,
         // all subsequent calls will use the cached value.
     }
}
```

Alternatively you can stick with the separate `Load` method and provide convenience factory methods to create the instance, set necessary properties, call `Load` and then return fully initialized `CachedDataReader`.